# Issue selecting CSS Selector for Google Tag Manager

Tags: css-selectors, google-tag-manager

I am new to GTM and am creating a trigger on a site for my company. I have tried all the ways I know how and looked at Simo Ahava's blog and cannot get my trigger to fire. I am making a trigger that fires on element click and wants to have the Click Element match the CSS selector but cannot get it to work properly.

This is what I see when I inspect the component on the page:

```
<div _ngcontent-my-app-c1="" class="page-complementary jss-page-complementary" id="jss-page-complementary" name="jss-page-complementary" sc-placeholder="">
<!---->
<!---->
<app-tab-stories _nghost-my-app-c26="" _ngcontent-my-app-c1="" class="ng-star-inserted">
<!---->
<div _ngcontent-my-app-c26="" id="our-stories" class="tab-stories tab-stories--option-three">
<div _ngcontent-my-app-c26="" class="tab-stories__inner">
<div _ngcontent-my-app-c26="" class="tab-stories__header">
<h2 _ngcontent-my-app-c26="" class="tab-stories__heading">Our Stories</h2></div><div _ngcontent-my-app-c26="" class="tab-stories__wrapper">
<mat-tab-group _ngcontent-my-app-c26="" class="tab-stories__tabs mat-tab-group mat-primary ng-animate-disabled mat-tab-group-dynamic-height" disableripple="" dynamicheight="">
<img _ngcontent-my-app-c9="" class="ng-tns-c9-25 tab-stories__image ng-trigger ng-trigger-fadeIn ng-star-inserted" id="app-deferred-image_id_d1e0186a-6714-c0b4-649e-b9234689c136" alt="null" src="/-/media/images/images-sc9/locations/pch/general-pch/patient-stories/lexie-gardiner-square.ashx?&amp;mw=400" style="">
```

I have tried the following CSS Selectors with no success, any help would be appreciated. The goal is to track that whenever anyone clicks on one of the stories under "Our Stories" they do not link off to anywhere just hidden content.

1. .tab-stories
2. .tab-stories__wraper
3. .tab-stories__image
4. div#our-stories
5. .tab-stories*
6. div#tab-stories*
7. div#tab-stories

Answer (score 0):

Try .tab-stories__tabs

If it doesn't work, edit your question and add a complete set of html with closing tags so that we could actually inject it into a page and see how it looks.

You don't need to try your selectors in GTM every time. That takes too long.

Just do the following:

1. Inspect your element to open the Elements tab in the Chrome Debugger.
2. press ctrl+f while the Elements tab is being focused and start typing your CSS selectors.
3. The search in the Elements tab is smart enough to not only match literal matches, but CSS selectors matches too.

Debugging your selectors through the Elements tab is the best way to make sure nothing else would trigger your rule on this page and to see what exactly will trigger it.